# Parse with data gathered from popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I am working on a Facebook app and I have a little bit of a trouble: I have my index.php and also a mypopup.php file. Hosted on heroku, if that matters in any way. Now what i need is that when a button is pressed on my index.php page, a popup window should appear, with the content of the mypopup.php file, that has a html form with a couple of checkboxes and a button. Now, the question is how can data from my popup window (checked items) be passed to my index.php and then work with that data in my index.php file?

For example:

> Checkbox1 data1 [checked]
>   Checkbox2 data2[unchecked]

The data related to checkbox1 should be passed to some function in index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to do this. I do it with some content I show in a lightbox. When the lightbox is done loading, I attach event handlers to all of the items I want to watch in the lightbox (`onchange` events for example). Then you can pass the data to index.php on the back-end using an AJAX request.

Also, I just realized (silly me), that if you have an HTML form, you can just change the action of the form to send the data to index.php instead of mypopup.php.

Either way will work. It depends on the specifics of the data and what you need to do with it.

Comment: Well, yeah, but **how** can I change the action of the form is such wat to send data to index.php?  How do I link them?

Comment: There's literally an `action` attribute for the `form` tag that you would change to `mypopup.php`.

Comment: I know the `action` attribute. What I don't know is how to change the form to send data to (actually) `index.php`

Comment: Sorry, I should have wrote `index.php`. Either way, whatever the `action` attribute is set to is where the form data will be sent.